# How to get User.hasAppPermission

Tags: facebook

For starters I hope facebook API burns in hell, in other news.

I'm trying to get a uid for which I need a session for a session I need to pass call_id sig. Which I have no clue how to get.

I'm following http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.hasAppPermission which does not give a single example code with it.

Can someone please tell me a simple way to get uid so I can find if he/she has given me publishing permissions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Has app permission was giving me trouble, so I got that in python/django on the server side adn then moved the flash.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  After some poking around, here is what worked for me ...

1. When they talk about the REST API, from the PHP perspective at least - they are talking about the [facebook_client library](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PHP#Official_PHP_Client_Library).
2. And then from your PHP file, you would add this to the top of the file, to use the REST API:

   **require_once '/facebook_client/facebook.php';**
3. And then here's what you need to check the 'create-event' permission:

   **$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);**

   **$user_id = $facebook->require_login();**

   **$perm = $facebook->api_client->users_hasAppPermission('create_event');**

   The return value is true or false. Do a search on google for 'FB.ApiClient.users_hasAppPermission' to get the API docs - they will only let me post one link today.

   Note that the permission names are the names you use with the **<fb:prompt-permission** FBML tag.

Comment: Thanks that works too :D Though I made a fbml if else statment piece which did it for me :)